# how to add picture from camera or gallery to recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to make the user take a picture of his phone or get a photo from gallery and add it to recyclerView list , and every time he takes a photo the recycler list increase automatically it works if i get the photo from drawable now i want to get it from camera or gallery. 
how to achieve it thanks

```
 public void dialogShowPhoto() {
    String takephoto = getString(R.string.take_photo);
    String chooseFromLibrary = getString(R.string.choose_from_library);
    String cancel = "cancel";
    String addPhoto = "add photo";
    final CharSequence[] items = {takephoto, chooseFromLibrary, cancel};
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(addPhoto);
    final String finalTakephoto = takephoto;
    final String finalChooseFromLibrary = chooseFromLibrary;
    final String finalCancel = cancel;
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals(finalTakephoto)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals(finalChooseFromLibrary)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            } else if (items[item].equals(finalCancel)) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        selectedImageWork.setAlpha(1f);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        // selectedImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(Integer.parseInt("270"));
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), mat, true);
        selectedImageWork.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);


    }
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        PlaceWorkModel placeWorkModel = new PlaceWorkModel(); // the model between activity and adapter
        placeWorkModel.setPhoto(Integer.parseInt(convertImage2Base64()));  // here i pass the photo
        picturesList.add(placeWorkModel);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}



// this method will convert the image to base64
public String convertImage2Base64() {
    Bitmap  bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) selectedImageWork.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
    return ("data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(image, 0));
}
```

Model Class

```
public class PlaceWorkModel {

private int photo;

public PlaceWorkModel(int photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public PlaceWorkModel() {
}

public int getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(int photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
```

Adapter

```
private Context mContext;
private List<PlaceWorkModel> picturesList;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView picture;



    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        picture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PlaceWorkRecycler_imageview_Picture);

    }
}


public PlaceWorkRecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<PlaceWorkModel> picturesList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.picturesList = picturesList;

}

@Override
public PlaceWorkRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.placework_recycler_adapterlayout, parent, false);
    return new PlaceWorkRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceWorkRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PlaceWorkModel listOfPictures = picturesList.get(position);
    // loading picturesList using Glide library
    Glide.with(mContext).load(listOfPictures.getPhoto())
            .into(holder.picture);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return picturesList.size();
}
```

here is the error LogCat

```
    12-16 17:50:47.630 11450-11476/com.foodservices.index.foodservices E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
12-16 17:50:47.636 11450-11476/com.foodservices.index.foodservices E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
12-16 17:50:49.317 11450-11450/com.foodservices.index.foodservices E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.foodservices.index.foodservices, PID: 11450
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/62/ORIGINAL/NONE/681675800 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F62/ORIGINAL/NONE/681675800} }} to activity {com.foodservices.index.foodservices/com.index.foodServices.common.view.activities.PlaceWorkActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
                                                                                         at com.index.foodServices.common.view.activities.PlaceWorkActivity.convertImage2Base64(PlaceWorkActivity.java:196)
                                                                                         at com.index.foodServices.common.view.activities.PlaceWorkActivity.onActivityResult(PlaceWorkActivity.java:184)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7267)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: it gives me this error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: Where? Please edit your question to include the logcat

Comment: @hossamrakha Would you like share your final error free code for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre not set the updated list into adapter.

in your adapter, add function update

```
public void updateList(List<PlaceWorkModel> picturesList) {
     this.picturesList = picturesList;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then,

```
 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        PlaceWorkModel placeWorkModel = new PlaceWorkModel(); // the model between activity and adapter
        placeWorkModel.setPhoto(Integer.parseInt(convertImage2Base64()));  // here i pass the photo
        picturesList.add(placeWorkModel);

        mAdapter.updateList(picturesList); // add this

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: it gives me this error   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 0):

maybe easyImage library will help you

[easyImage library](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage)

here is an example of how to use the library in order to take a picture from device and save it into your app and after that you can set it to your view

```
    private void OpenImage() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Options");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (items[i].equals("Camera")) {
                EasyImage.openCamera(EditorActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[i].equals("Gallery")) {
                EasyImage.openGallery(EditorActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    EasyImage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, new DefaultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onImagePicked(File imageFile, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            switch (type) {
                case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
                    Glide.with(EditorActivity.this)
                            .load(imageFile)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(img);
                    saveImage(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    break;
                case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:
                    Glide.with(EditorActivity.this)
                            .load(imageFile)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(img);
                    saveImage(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void saveImage(String imagePath) {
    pictureChanged = true;
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
        byte[] image = new byte[file.available()];
        file.read(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your **convertImage2Base64** try changing it to something like below

```
public byte[] convertImage2Base64() {
    Bitmap  bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) selectedImageWork.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte[] image = Base64.decode(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return image;
}
```

and make changes to your model like below.

```
    public class PlaceWorkModel {

private byte[] photo;

public PlaceWorkModel(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public PlaceWorkModel() {
}

public byte[] getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
```

I assume you are able to call functions in fragment/activity and get the image from the gallery or camera the only problem is with glide which is not loading the image. Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: try getting byte array using this

Comment: byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: still the same but i think now the error in this line Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: why don't you pass this bMapRotate in parameters of the  convertImage2Base64 directly and get it converted from bitmap directly instead of  getting bitmap drawble and then casting

Comment: can you give an example please? or add you soultion on my code.

Comment: can anyone please give me a solution of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497289/how-can-i-add-capture-image-and-from-gallary-in-recyclerview